# Change Keyboard Input Language Programmatically

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I am developing an application in which i need to allow the user to change the input keys shown in the default keyboard, upon request or by default, for example, i may prompt the user at the beginning to select the default language and after that, whenever the default keyboard is used, the app always displays the keys of the keyboard the selected language,

I know this is possible, because in default keyboard app, when multiple input methods are selected, then long pressing the spacebar allows to change the input methods at runtime, if this is possible then my requirement is also possible...

I dont want to prompt for default keyboard like following:

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

I dont want to change the locale and restart my activity all the time like:

```
Resources res = getBaseContext().getResources();
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("ru".toLowerCase());
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
Log.i("inside onStart","after ever");   
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I just want to show the keyboard input in my desired language.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

After doing some research here and there found the answer, first of all you have to create a custom keyboard View which extends keyboardView and in it create static key value variable like

```
static final int KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH_ENG = -102;
static final int KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH_URDU = -103;
```

after that in your IME class where you have implemented the inputMethodService, create the keyboards inside the onInitializeInterface override function. like

```
mSymbolsKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty2);
mEngQwertyKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.eng_qwerty);
```

after this add these final static keys in the onKey override function as switch cases, and in the cases set the keyboards accordingly:

```
setKeyboard(mEngQwertyKeyboard);
```

Comment: for different language required to create different xml of keyboard layout?

Comment: only system apps can set custom keyboard.

Comment: after givinig permission of write secure settings , application got crashed. It said system permission are alllowed only by system apps.

Comment: Can you please describe proper and whole description , i'm confused how to implement these etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can change keyboard without user notification only and only if your app is running as a System app for security reasons.

You need to give Android permission first in your app's AndroidManifest.xml

```
"android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"
```

Then you need to determine id of your keyboard.

-> To know id, you need to keep your keyboard default from setting menu manually then put this print somewhere,

```
System.out.println(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD));
```

Once you print id and you know your keyboard id you can do as per below 
( I have changed my default keyboard to Japanese )

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

//imeManager.showInputMethodPicker(); //This is to see available keyboards.
imeManager.setInputMethod(null,"jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn/.OpenWnnJAJP");
```

Enjoy !!

Comment: after givinig permission of write secure settings , application got crashed. It said system permission are alllowed only by system apps.

Comment: only system apps can set custom keyboard.