# Android change keyboard language programmatically

Tags: android, locale, android-softkeyboard

I'm building a single purpose app for one and only one device model. Therefore I allow switching languages within the app as I do not want the user to open the settings.

I was successful in changing the Locale.

**I was unsuccessful switching the language input (understand switching the keyboard from thai to english and english to thai).**

Note: It comes from factory with English and Thai language inputs already installed and available.

Note 2 : I've seen a load of solution on google but I find none of them precise enough to know if it's doable and how to perform this. I mention this because I'd like to avoid one more copy paste of this solution for eg : [Change Keyboard Input Language Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261166/change-keyboard-input-language-programmatically). It might be a good solution, but I just don't get it.

Comment: `but I just don't get it` what exactly is that you don't get? is your app a system app?

Comment: My app isn't a system app. Do I need it to be a system app to be able to switch input language ? Is it a setting I have to enable manually ? Because I've got a lot of devices and I'd rather avoid to change manually set this up one by one.

Comment: I think that you can do that only if your app is a system app. Or as alternative you can just develop your own in-app keyboard, and switch it's language with the app language

Comment: Seems like I need a rooted device which isn't an option for me